# Parse JSON to webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I retrieve data from mysql by php and save it as `String`

```
 read= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s,"iso-8859-1"),8);
 String line=null;
 while ((line=read.readLine()) !=null)
 {
     text+=line+"\n";
 }
```

output is

```
[{"DATE_OF_TEXT":"2015-05-06","total_rate_FORuser":"9.90000"},
 {"DATE_OF_TEXT":"2015-05-30","total_rate_FORuser":"5.10000"}]
```

How parse `JSON` to my Javascript file in webview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass in the string after the page is loaded, you could use

```
String jsText = "javascript:addData('" + text + "');");
webView.loadUrl(jsText);
```

EDIT : In your case, modify the url with the string:

```
String urlWithData = yourUrl + "?data=" + text;
webView.loadUrl(urlWithData);
```

Then in the javascript, first get the text using window.location.search

```
var jsontext = window.location.search.substring(1).split('=')[1];
```

And then, convert the JSON text into a JavaScript object, using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsontext);
```

Comment: how i parse it to my javascript file

Comment: Depending on your use case, there are different ways of accomplishing this. I have updated my answer with one way to do this.

Comment: where i put this url  "file:///android_asset/example.html"

Comment: Oh. I get what you are doing. Gimme a sec to update the answer.

Comment: i thank you about your reply but i have another problem
my data =
 [{"DATE_OF_TEXT":"2015-05-06","total_rate_FORuser":"9.90000"}]
but show this way
[{%22DATE_OF_TEXT%22:%222015-05-06%22,%22total_rate_FORuser%22:%229.90000%22}}
you have any solution ?

Comment: i add some code after your code
var find = '%22';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
var str = jsontext.replace(re, '\"');

Comment: use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) on the text.